# Collect all data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes

My webpage is dynamically generated with, data-runway-link, data-video-link, data-backstage-link, there will be more in the future.....

The patterns are always like this data-xxx-link, what I want to do are, extract the "xxx" text in each of them store them inside an array so that I can refer each of the info using javascript

```
 <li> <a data-season="Designer Profiles" data--link="123" data-video-link="1233"> </a></li>
 <li> <a data-season="Spring/Summer 2014" data-Runway-link="abc" data-video-link="abc"> 3.1 Phillip Lim</a></li>
 <li> <a data-season="Spring/Summer 2014" data-Runway-link="abc" data-video-link="abc"> Acne Studios</a></li>
 <li> <a data-season="Spring/Summer 2014" data-Runway-link="abc" data-video-link="abc"> Aigner</a></li>
 <li> <a data-season="Spring/Summer 2014" data-Backstage-link="abc" data-video-link="abc"> Alexander McQueen</a></li>
 <li> <a data-season="Spring/Summer 2014" data-Runway-link="abc" data-video-link="abc"> Alexander Wang</a></li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).data())
})
```

result will look like:

```
{season: 'Designer Profiles', 'runwayLink':'abc' ...}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/NnHqQ/5/

**STEP2:** removing word link from keys

easiest way would be:

```
function removeLiknfromKey(data) {
    var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(data);
    var new_jsonstr = jsonstr.replace(/Link":/g, '":');
    var new_obj = JSON.parse(new_jsonstr);
    return new_obj;
}
```

you will have an object with XXX names only.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/NnHqQ/6/

now you can use it nicely, using only name:

```
data.runway, data.video, data.season ... etc
```

Comment: you can collect all this data, and keep working with JSON object. with kays and data for it. this is another story! .data() collecting all set of data, of element. even set by script.

Answer (score 2):

When you access an element that has any `data-*` attributes with jQuery, you can access an object containing all of the `data-*` elements using the `data()` function.

For example, if you had an element like this:

```
 <a id="elem" data-season="Designer Profiles" data-link="123" data-video-link="1233"> </a>
```

You could do something like this:

```
var element_data = $( "#elem" ).data();
```

Now, each of the keys within `element_data` will have each data attribute.

```
element_data[ "season" ]; // "Designer Profiles";
element_data[ "link" ]; // "123";
element_data[ "video-link" ]; // "1233";
```

Here is the relevant documentation for the `data()` function: http://api.jquery.com/data/
As you can see, the same function acts as a getter and a setter function. So to retrieve a specific key of data you would do something like this:

```
var video_link = $( "#elem" ).data( "video-link" ); // "1233"
```

You could also **set** the `video-link` value:

```
var new_video_link_value = "some other value";
var video_link = $( "#elem" ).data( "video-link", new_video_link_value );
```

---

To put all of this to use and to answer your question, what you would do is something like this:

```
var elems = $("li > a"); // extract all of the relevant anchor tags
var elem_data = [];
$.each( elems, function( index, elem ){
  elem_data.push( $(elem).data() );
});
```

You will now have all of the data attributes for each anchor tag within the `elem_data` array. What might be a better idea is to give each anchor tag some sort of identifier so that you can map the data back to the relevant element that it came from.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('li a').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).data())
});
```